Azure SQL Managed Instance and Microsoft Entra ID authentication with Transactional Replication
I am setting up transactional replication with an Azure SQL MI as my pub/dist, and Azure SQL Database as my sub.  I've got everything working using sql authentication, but when I try to configure it using Microsoft Entra integrated authentication, it won't allow me.
For example, sp_addlogreader_agent, the @publisher_security_mode supports this type of authentication as of SQL Server 2022 (16.x) CU 6.  However when I try to specify it via value of 3, I get error:
EXEC sys.sp_addlogreader_agent @job_login = 'repluser', @job_password = '<pwd>', @publisher_security_mode = 3

Results:

Msg 14266, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_MSrepl_addlogreader_agent, Line 83 [Batch Start Line 12]
The specified '@publisher_security_mode' is invalid (valid values are: 0, 1).


Makes sense, SQL Server 2022 does not equal Azure SQL Managed Instance or Azure SQL Database.
